# Magento Newsletters take over 24 hours to send

Tags: magento

I have a little under 7000 newsletter subscribers. I run an online shop and would like to send out daily newsletters for my Deal Of The Day. This is currently impossible as it takes at least an entire day for my newsletter to get to all of its subscribers. Please advise

Comment: Use a proper email solution like Mailchimp. Magento has plugins to pass data to your Mailchimp lists.

Comment: Magento isn't designed to send bulk email.  Do what @ceejayoz said.  Bronto is also another good solution: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bronto-extension-for-magento.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use some  email marketing solution to send emails.
Choose from list below:
1. Mailchimp (easiest of all)
2. Netcore (provides full solution)
3. Icubes
4. Sendy.co (cheapest of all)

Using these you will also be able to track your email response like opens, clicks etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can hack Magento to send more emails; however, your web hosting provider will probably pull your plug unless they specifically allow mass Commercial Email.

You will be black listed as a spammer if you don't understand how to set up domain keys, SPF and a series of other items. One of the biggies is that you shouldn't be using port 25 unencrypted traffic without authentication. Any bypassing of this changes your bulk email output to UCE (Unsolicited Commercial Email) in their books. The other biggie is not having an unsubscribe method present in every email sent.

If you have the technical capacity to be running your own web server (not have to use a hosting provider) then Amazon's SMS is probably a good choice if you have Ashley Shroeder's SMTP module installed.

If you don't have the technical capability, then using an ESP (eMail Service Provider) like MailChimp is a far better way. They take care of a lot of the technical detail with bounces, email list management, unsubscribe, etc. to help prevent you from being blacklisted as a UCE source.